# How do I put labels on the grid lines of the table?

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML and CSS as follows

```css
.flex {
  font: 14px Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex>div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>{data['player1-pre']}</div>
  <div>{data['player2-pre']}</div>
  <div>{data['player1-post']}</div>
  <div>{data['player2-post']}</div>
</div>
```

This renders as follows:[image]

I would like to add labels on the grid lines like this [image]

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I brute forced it, but here's something:

```css
.flex-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex {
  font: 14px Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:5px;
}
.grid-lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid-lines > div {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
}
.space {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.inline {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>efg</div>
    <div>hijk</div>
    <div>lmnop</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-lines">
    <div>top</div>
    <div class="space">
      <div class="inline">middle 1</div>
      <div class="inline">middle 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lot's of flex displays and a bit of absolute positioning to get the text on the gridlines in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three grids to achieve this; one for the items, one for vertical labels, one for horizontal labels:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="grid" id="actual">
    <!-- <div class="item"><span class="text"></span></div> -->
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
  <div class="grid" id="vertical"></div>
  <div class="grid" id="horizontal"></div>
</div>
```

...of which the latter two will overlay the first.

Here's a visualization using ASCII art (`1` means `1fr`, etc.):

```
#actual:                                     #vertical:                       
    1       1       1       1                    1       1       1       1    
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐            ┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│       │       │       │       │          1 │       │       │       │       │
│  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │ 1          ├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│       │       │       │       │            │       │       │       │       │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤          2 │  _B_  │  _B_  │  _B_  │  _B_  │
│       │       │       │       │            │       │       │       │       │
│  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │ 1          ├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│       │       │       │       │            │       │       │       │       │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤          2 │  _B_  │  _B_  │  _B_  │  _B_  │
│       │       │       │       │            │       │       │       │       │
│  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │  abc  │ 1          ├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│       │       │       │       │          1 │       │       │       │       │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘            └───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘


#horizontal:                                 #wrapper:                        
  1     2       2       2     1                  1       1       1       1    
┌───┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───┐            ┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
│   │  A_C  │  A_C  │  A_C  │   │ 1        1 │  abc A_C abc A_C abc A_C abc  │
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
├───┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┤            ├──_B_──┼──_B_──┼──_B_──┼──_B_──┤
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
│   │  A_C  │  A_C  │  A_C  │   │ 1        1 │  abc A_C abc A_C abc A_C abc  │
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
├───┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───┤            ├──_B_──┼──_B_──┼──_B_──┼──_B_──┤
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
│   │  A_C  │  A_C  │  A_C  │   │ 1        1 │  abc A_C abc A_C abc A_C abc  │
│   │       │       │       │   │            │       │       │       │       │
└───┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───┘            └───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

We can clearly see that `#vertical` has more than one row, and `#horizontal` one column, comparing to `#actual`. Let `--rows` and `--columns` be the number of rows and columns of `#actual`, here's our CSS skeleton:

```css
/* Create layers */

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#vertical,
#horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Base styles for all 3 grids and their items */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/* grid-template-areas */

#actual {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

#vertical {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--rows) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

#horizontal {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--columns) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
}
```

To prevent vertical and horizontal labels from overlapping grid lines, use [`isolation: isolate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation) on `.item` and [`mix-blend-mode: multiply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) on `.text`:

```
#vertical .item,
#horizontal .item {
  isolation: isolate;
}

#vertical .text,
#horizontal .text {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 var(--gap);
  color: #f00;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Note that, since we are skipping the first and last row of `#vertical`, along with the first and last column of `#horizontal`, we need to fix the padding of both those `.grid`s and their corresponding items. The math behind this is left as an exercise for the reader:

```css
:root {
  --gap: 2rem;
}

.grid {
  padding: var(--gap);
}

#vertical {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--rows) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  padding: calc(var(--gap) / 2) var(--gap);
}

#horizontal {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--columns) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
  padding: var(--gap) calc(var(--gap) / 2);
}
```

```js
function fixPadding() {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent = `
#vertical .item:nth-child(-n + ${columns}),
#vertical .item:nth-last-child(-n + ${columns}),
#horizontal .item:nth-child(${columns + 1}n),
#horizontal .item:nth-last-child(${columns + 1}n) {
  padding: 0;
}
`;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Try it (randomized content and dimension):

```js
/* The only thing necessary is fixPadding() */

const [wrapper, actual, vertical, horizontal] = [
  '#wrapper',
  '#actual',
  '#vertical',
  '#horizontal'
].map(selector => document.querySelector(selector));

const randomIntInRange_0_10 = randomIntSmallerThan(10);
const randomIntInRange_0_27 = randomIntSmallerThan(27);

const [height, width] = [8, 4].map(max => 2 + randomIntSmallerThan(max)());
const gap = randomIntInRange_0_10() * 0.2;

wrapper.style.setProperty('--gap', gap + 'rem');
wrapper.style.setProperty('--rows', height);
wrapper.style.setProperty('--columns', width);

fillGrid(actual, height, width, randomText);
fillGrid(
  vertical, height + 1, width,
  i => i % height ? 'vertical' : ''
);
fillGrid(
  horizontal, height, width + 1,
  (_, j) => j % width ? 'horizontal' : ''
);

fixPadding();


/* Functions */

function randomIntSmallerThan(number) {
  return () => (Math.random() * number) | 0;
}

function randomText() {
  const length = randomIntInRange_0_10() + 5;

  const text = Array.from({ length }, () => {
    const code = randomIntInRange_0_27();

    return (code ? String.fromCharCode(code + 96) : ' ')[
      `to${Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'Upper' : 'Lower'}Case`
    ]();
  });

  return text.join('');
}

function fillGrid(element, height, width, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      const item = document.createElement('div');
      const text = document.createElement('span');

      text.textContent = callback(i, j);

      item.classList.add('item');
      text.classList.add('text');

      item.appendChild(text);
      element.appendChild(item);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Remove padding for:
 * * First {width} and last {width} #vertical items
 * * First and last item of each #horizontal row.
**/
function fixPadding() {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent = `
#vertical .item:nth-child(-n + ${width}),
#vertical .item:nth-last-child(-n + ${width}),
#horizontal .item:nth-child(${width + 1}n),
#horizontal .item:nth-last-child(${width + 1}n) {
  padding: 0;
}
`;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --padding: 1em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--gap);
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: var(--padding);
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#actual {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

#vertical {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--rows) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  padding: calc(var(--gap) / 2) var(--gap);
}

#horizontal {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(calc(var(--columns) - 1), 2fr) 1fr;
  padding: var(--gap) calc(var(--gap) / 2);
}

#actual,
#actual .item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#vertical,
#horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#vertical .item,
#horizontal .item {
  isolation: isolate;
}

#vertical .text,
#horizontal .text {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 var(--gap);
  color: #f00;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="grid" id="actual"></div>
  <div class="grid" id="vertical"></div>
  <div class="grid" id="horizontal"></div>
</div>
```